# Contradicting results with AMP-test-tool & Google Search Console

Tags: amp-html, google-search-console

I have recently added AMP-versions to the articles on my educational platform https://lernzettel.org/. Googles Search Console, however, evaluates my AMP-pages as being invalid (right part of the screen):
[image]
In contradiction to this, the AMP-test-tool states, that the AMP-Pages are valid (left part of the screen).

The links checked are identical (marked in blue).

Additional information:
- lernzettel.org uses vue.js, the AMP-references are injected via JS (only option possible)

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Update:
Whether the AMP-Page is evaluated as being valid seems to rely on how it is referenced:
Valid: https://search.google.com/test/amp?id=8oH5S6UCRsNodkip-jqtkA

Invalid (in spite of using the same url): https://search.google.com/test/amp?skip_amp_follow=true&id=CAQq01vCsK2LGzBmJ4I2Xw

Comment: Does the google search console output any errors ? It could be a discrepancy between testing services.

Comment: Nothing beyond what the screenshot shows.

Comment: I think it could be disperancy between the testing tools. I'd submit an issue on the AMP Project's Github.

Comment: check your non amp page https://lernzettel.org/kurze-einfuhrung-in-die-gottesbeweise, when it load does not show in view source <link data-vue-meta="1" rel="amphtml" href="https://amp.lernzettel.org/kurze-einfuhrung-in-die-gottesbeweise/index.html">, I think non amp page render issue

Answer (score 0):

```
<link data-vue-meta="1" rel="amphtml" href="https://amp.lernzettel.org/kurze-einfuhrung-in-die-gottesbeweise/index.html">
```

In non AMP page `<link>` tag should be present in the raw HTML, and not injected via JavaScript.

[For More Information](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amphtml/?referrer=ampproject.org#amp-document-discovery)

Comment: So - a Vue powered blog (without SSR, dynamic rendering etc) can not be combined with AMP? ‍♂️